# Determine the sex of indian flapshell turtle

Tags: turtles, gender-differentiation

I have brought an Indian flapshell turtle at my home but I am unaware regarding its sex So please help me to find the gender of my pet

Comment: The most reliable way to get an answer is to take the turtle toa vet who specializes in reptiles. Failing that, websearching "determine sex turtle" finds a number of suggestions in details of shell shape, tail and cloaca shape, lengthof claws, size, and so on. None of those are 100% reliable but when taken together they may answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Males tend to have a longer thicker tail than a female only when they are fully grown. Females tend to have shorter nails also. The males have longer nails on their front feet. This is in general of turtles.